# What is this shrub and has it come back from the dead?

Tags: identification, shrubs, repair

We had this deciduous shrub in our lawn for many years. Its height was about 1.5m - 2m. This photo is from a couple of years ago.

[image]

Strange thing is that this spring it seemed to have died. We reckoned to return that area to lawn. I cut the dead plant right back to its stump (thinking to remove that later) and turfed over the remainder.

Not long ago I noticed fresh growth from the stump. Is the full shrub now going to come back from the dead and be good as ever?

And can anyone identify it (either from the old photo, or from the new shoots?).

Here's the fresh growth (if you look closely, you'll see that the shoots are definitely coming from the original stump.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In form and in leaf, your shrub looks a somewhat like a privet ([Ligustrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligustrum_vulgare)). Compare [*here*](http://www.arborea.se/liguatro.htm) and [*here*](http://www.kuleuven-kortrijk.be/bioweb/foto.php?link=photos/L/ligustrum%20vulgare-wilde%20liguster-03194.jpg&titel=wild%20privet%20-%20Ligustrum%20vulgare). It clearly has opposite leaves. Has it ever had small round black (or green or white or yellow) fruit? But, I am guessing, you know what a privet looks like.

Comment: i wish i could remember flower/fruit. i'll check with mrs

Comment: probably not a privet, as these have mildly serrated edges, whereas privets have smooth edges.

Comment: @TeaDrinker: Do the leaves have serrated edges?

Comment: What happened later on with your bush? :)

Answer (score 3):

Your plant has some kind of flavor? With small spike flowers? It's his scent similar to lemon? If so, it reminds me of lemon verbena (Aloysia citrodora). Check to see [if it can help you.](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloysia_citrodora)

[image: er]

[pianta http://www.ilgiardinodegliangeli.net/files/Lippia-citriodora.jpg](http://www.ilgiardinodegliangeli.net/files/Lippia-citriodora.jpg)
[image: pi2]

Answer (score 2):

I cannot identify the plant but it seems to be the same plant based on the angle that the new growth is coming up. Maybe all the plant needed was for the old bush to be removed so that it could get sunlight and create new and healthier growth.